# Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\MyController::$cookieJar

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, cookiejar

So my controller looks as follows:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Cookie\CookieJar;
use Cookie;

class MyController extends Controller {

    public function __construct(CookieJar $cookieJar)
    {
        $this->id = $this->getID();
        $this->cookieJar = $cookieJar;
    }

    private function getID()
    {
        if (!isset($_COOKIE["ID"])){
            $id = 20;
            $this->cookieJar->queue('ID', $id, 60);
        }

        return $id;
    }
```

But I keep getting an error

> Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\MyController::$cookieJar

In getID function.

What am I doing wrong? Would highly appreciate any possible help!

Comment: Use instead of use Illuminate\Cookie\CookieJar; use CookieJar

Comment: @GM.Akbar then I get "Class CookieJar does not exist"

Comment: What is your Laravel version?

Comment: Initialize 2 variables `$id = 0` and `$cookieJar = null` before _construct and that should do it.

Comment: I think you have wrong declaration in your constructor "$this" means from your controller but you didn't have the ID var or function.

Comment: @GM.Akbar 5.2 
KuKeC if I write just "$cookieJar = null@, I get "syntax error, unexpected '$cookieJar' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)", but if I make it private or public, I get "Call to a member function queue() on a non-object"

Comment: Then you have to do next, initialize them as private/public, in constructor first do  `$this->cookieJar = $cookieJar;` and then do `$this->id = $this->getID();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically problem in your code not that cookieJar class. Below is the correct code for controller:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Cookie\CookieJar;
use Cookie;

class MyController extends Controller {

    protected $id;
    protected $cookieJar;

    public function __construct(CookieJar $cookieJar)
    {
        $this->cookieJar = $cookieJar;
        $this->id = $this->getID();
    }

    private function getID()
    {
        if (!isset($_COOKIE["ID"])){
            $id = 20;
            $this->cookieJar->queue('ID', $id, 60);
        }

        return $id;
    }
```

When we are using any property in all the functions of controllers for carry some value then we have to define these properties. Please check my code.
One more thing, the order of properties also incorrect in constructor method. Because you are using a function `getID()` which is using `$cookieJar` property. So you have to define that property first then use second property `$id` in constructor method.

I think this will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you call the getID method, and in the getID method, you use your cookiejar, but the cookiejar has not yet been initialised.

If you switch the method calls around, it should work

```
 public function __construct(CookieJar $cookieJar)
 {
    $this->cookieJar = $cookieJar;
    $this->id = $this->getID();
 }
```